# Bootstrap class "panel-body" div can not reduce the width of table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I test my html code with bootstrap css at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mrjv2hau/13/) .

I want to reduce the width of id named "mytable1".
I use this:

```
 <div id="mytable1" class="panel-body" width="200px">
```

But it has no effect.

Now "mytable1" takes up the whole screen width.
But I want to reduce it to the red rectangle scope,about half of the screen:
[image]

The cells in the table can smaller.

Where can I modify?

Comment: Because you provided the width inline which has preference over the css

Comment: Sir,I don't  understand what you mean. Can't I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I konw how to modify my code.

**Div element has not attribute width**,this code is not right:

```
<div id="mytable1" class="panel-body" width="200px">
```

I must use:`style="width:200px"`.

And then the code has effect.

```
<div id="mytable1" class="panel-body" style="width:200px">
```

Answer (score 0):

your div with id="mytable1" has a 200px width but the table inside this div overflow in x direction and you must fix this item
for example add width to inputs

```
input[type="text"] {
  width: 98px;
}
```